# Actionscript 3 game Character (Flashdevelop)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, character

I am currently trying to make a game in Flashdevelop. The language I am using is Actionscript 3.

How can I implement my design for the character? 
I tried to embed the image file, but flashdevelop gives me errors.

```
public class Player extends MovieClip 
    {
        [Embed(source="../Images/Main Character.png")]
        public var floor:int = 684;
```

This is the error: An Embed variable must not have an existing value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add next code after `Embed` tag:

```
public var MainCharacter:Class;
```

To add this image to the stage write:

```
var bmp:Bitmap = new MainCharacter() as Bitmap;
addChild(bmp);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It really helped me out! I am having problems with collision detection. The character ends up floating in the air, when I try to jump on a block. The image of the block is probably not in the right place. The image is in the right bottom corner of the collision detection, I think. Is there a way to properly position an image for an object?

Comment: The collision detection and the square are in the same place, when I replace the image with a plain black sqaure made with this.graphics......

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no need for `MovieClip` here, just extend `Sprite` if you need a container.

If you do not want to create another child like @subdan shows in his answer, you can tie the class directly to the embedded content, by placing the embed line right above the `class` line:

```
[Embed(source="../Images/Main Character.png")]
public class Player extends Bitmap
```